# Word wrap algorithm not printing as expected

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, word-wrap

I want to develop a recursive word wrap algorithm that takes a specified string and wrap length (the maximum number of characters on one line) to return a wrapped output at the input length. I don't want it to break apart words. So for example, `This is the first paragraph that you need to input` with length 20 returns as:

```
This is the first
paragraph that you
need to input
```

However, my function currently prints:

```
This is the first paragraph
that you need to input
```

My code:

```
def wrap(text, lineLength):

    temp=text.find(" ",lineLength-1)
    if temp == -1:
        return text
    else:
        return text[:temp+1]+'\n'+wrap(text[temp+1:], lineLength)

print wrap("This is the first paragraph that you need to input", 20);
```

Why isn't this doing what I expect it to, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know if you're doing this as an exercise, or you're actually trying to implement this, but Python does have a module for this: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/textwrap.html

Comment: This is indeed as an exercise for my own benefit, but I'm also curious about the built-in module. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some changes your code works:

```
def wrap(text, lineLength):
    if len(text) <= lineLength: return text
    temp = text.rfind(" ", 0, lineLength - 1)
    if temp == -1: 
        return text
    else:
        return text[:temp+1]+'\n'+wrap(text[temp+1:], lineLength)
```

With this output:

```
This is the first 
paragraph that you 
need to input
```

But you may also want to enforce a hypen when there is no space to break:

```
def wrap(text, lineLength):
    if len(text) <= lineLength: return text
    temp = text.rfind(" ", 0, lineLength - 1)
    if temp == -1: 
        return text[:lineLength - 1] + '-\n' + wrap(
            text[lineLength - 1:], lineLength)
    else:
        return text[:temp+1] + '\n' + wrap(text[temp+1:], lineLength)

print wrap("Thisisthefirstparagraphthatyouneed to input", 20)
```

This results in:

```
Thisisthefirstparag-
raphthatyouneed to 
input
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm studying algorithms, so I'm glad the issue was mostly just syntax and that corner case.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `find` with the start argument set to 19, which means you find the *first* space *after* the 20th character.  What you want is to find the *last* space *before* the 20th character.  Take a look at using `rfind` instead.

Comment: Cool, thanks. My Python skills aren't what they used to be :/

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding which wordwrap algorithm you're using, I suspect the funky bit is this:

```
temp=text.find(" ",lineLength-1)
if temp == -1:
    return text
```

If you don't find a space within the first `lineLength-1` characters, you just return the text verbatim.  Don't you need to recurse there or something?

Comment: That's not actually the cause of the problem, although it is another potential problem with the code.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  The off-by-one error you've identified is probably the prime cause of the incorrect behavior, but the termination condition seems obviously wrong by most definitions of "word wrap".

Answer (score 0):

```
def wrap(str,l):     
    ll=list(str)
    i=l
    while i < len(str):
        ll.insert(i,"\n")
        i=i+l
    nstr="".join(ll)
    print nstr
```

Output:
This is the first pa

ragraph that you ne

ed to input